# App crashes when no internet during Retrofit2 Get request

Tags: android, kotlin, get, retrofit2

My application seems to keep crashing giving me an `E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main` error when i try to make a Get request to a server and there is no internet. I expected the app to run but no data be displayed.

`Log.i("getStoreData()" , "Inside the coroutine before getData")`

this is the last log that I have put myself gets printed before the app crashes.

```
 private fun getStoreData() {

        Log.i("getStoreData()", " inside getStoreData")

        val job = coroutineScope.launch {
            Log.i("getStoreData()" , "Inside the coroutine before getData")
            var data = StoreAPI.retrofitService.getData()
            Log.i("getStoreData()" , "Inside the coroutine after getData")
            try {
                var storeData = data.stores

                _status.value = "Success: ${storeData.size} Stores received"

                if(storeData.size > 0){
                    _stores.value = storeData
                }
            } catch (t: Throwable) {

                Log.i("Retrofit catch block", _status.value)
                _status.value = "Failure: " + t.message

                t.printStackTrace()
            }
        }


    }
```

StoreAPIService.kt

```
private const val URL = "http://sandbox.bottlerocketapps.com/BR_Android_CodingExam_2015_Server/"


private val moshi = Moshi.Builder().add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory()).build()

private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
    .baseUrl(URL)
    .build()

interface StoreAPIService{

    //Initially was using Jake Wharton's library for retrofit2 kotlin coroutines support but it has been deprecated since the support
    // addition of the suspend keyword in retrofit 2.6.0
    //Suspend does all the task of coroutines for us by just adding it before the function declaration
    @GET("stores.json")
    suspend fun getData():
            Data //return Data object because Data has access to the Store JSON Object/Array
}

object StoreAPI{
    val retrofitService: StoreAPIService by lazy {
        retrofit.create(StoreAPIService::class.java)
    }
}
```

[image]

Any idea why?

**EDIT:**

I cannot use these network connectivity functions because I my fragment is not connected to any activity and the fragment is connected to a viewModel. Therefore this line of code doesn't work as there is no context to bound it to. If you have a work around for this that would be great too.

`ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);`

Comment: have you not added any internet check before api calling?

Comment: @quicklearner I'm following a tutorial and they don't have one either but there app doesn't crash.

Comment: Have you added the internet permission in manifest?

Comment: look at this documentation

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-status-type

Comment: @PrajwalW Yes, I have. The app works fine when connected to the internet. I get the data and it is displayed. Only when there is no internet the app crashes

Comment: Show the error msg in debugger where it shows the piece of code where the crash actually happened. The image which you postes is the log value which will always get printed as you r calling that function

Comment: Check the log of your catch block

Comment: @PrajwalW that's the whole thing, the log of the catch block does not get printed. I don't know why.

Comment: Add a log under your try block and check the status value data in the log and post the image of the same in case of no internet

Comment: @PrajwalW no custom logging happens when there is no internet. It just crashes directly. Here is the project rar incase you want to run it yourself:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wzFifZXLjCZQpi5E_EOH_qyhxnIWsGZZ

Comment: @PrajwalW the error stack was not being printed because i had assigned the result of the coroutine to an unsued val job. After i removed that val job portion, i get the output but the app still crashes

Comment: See that the reason y logs r so important!

Comment: @PrajwalW but still the sample app I am referring to doesn't crash when there is no internet. Why does mine?

Comment: @PrajwalW this is the link to the sample project: https://github.com/udacity/andfun-kotlin-mars-real-estate

The branch is step 4 solution

Answer (score 1):

Try using this
Create Class For **NetworkConnectionDetection**

**Manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

**NetworkConnection** Class

```
class NetworkConnection(val context: Context) : LiveData<Boolean>() {
var connectionManger: ConnectivityManager =
    context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager

lateinit var netwrokCallback: ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback

override fun onActive() {
    super.onActive()
    updateConnection()
    when {
        Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N -> {
            connectionManger.registerDefaultNetworkCallback(NetworkConnectioncallback())
        }
        Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP -> {
            lollipopNetworkRequest()
        }
        else -> {
            context.registerReceiver(
                networkReciever(),
                IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)
            )
        }
    }
}

/*override fun onInactive() {
    super.onInactive()
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        connectionManger.unregisterNetworkCallback(NetworkConnectioncallback())
    } else {
        context.unregisterReceiver(networkReciever())
    }
}*/

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
fun lollipopNetworkRequest() {
    val requestBuilder = NetworkRequest.Builder()
        .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)
        .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
        .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET)
    connectionManger.registerNetworkCallback(
        requestBuilder.build(),
        NetworkConnectioncallback()
    )
}

fun NetworkConnectioncallback(): ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        netwrokCallback = object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
            override fun onLost(network: Network) {
                super.onLost(network)
                postValue(false)
            }

            override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {
                super.onAvailable(network)
                postValue(true)
            }
        }
        return netwrokCallback
    } else {
        throw IllegalAccessError("Error!")
    }

}

fun networkReciever() = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        updateConnection()
    }

}

fun updateConnection() {
    val activeNetwork: NetworkInfo? = connectionManger.activeNetworkInfo
    postValue((activeNetwork?.isConnected == true))
}
```

}

Now Inside your **Activity/Fragment** Check the connection either it is connected or not. Here is how it will be achieved

```
  val networkConnection = NetworkConnection(requireContext())
        networkConnection.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { isConnected ->
            if (isConnected) {
                // Do what ever you want to do
            } else {
               // Show No internet connection message
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

NB: before making any Network call or sending any requesting   you must ensure that the device is connected to internet. I entice you to write a simple function to check if you're connected, if you're connected then you can send the request or make a network call.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add internet checks before calling your retrofit service because to get some data from server, internet connectivity is mandatory

Answer (score -1):

This method checks whether mobile is connected to internet and returns true
if connected:

```
private boolean isNetworkConnected() {
     ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();
}
```

in manifest,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Edit: This method actually checks if device is connected to internet(There is
     a possibility it's connected to a network but not to internet).

```
public boolean isInternetAvailable() {
    try {
          InetAddress ipAddr = InetAddress.getByName("google.com"); 
          //You can replace it with your name
          return !ipAddr.equals("");

     }catch (Exception e) {
          return false;
     }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This will tell you if you're connected to a network:

```
boolean connected = false;
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if(connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED || 
            connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
        //we are connected to a network
        connected = true;
    }
    else
        connected = false;
```

Answer (score -1):

I also followed that tutorial, but I don't remember it having an offline mode. That is an option that you have to integrate on yourself.

When you create the viewModel, because it has an init block, it makes the call to the API and if you don't have an Internet connection, it crashes.

So you should write the init viewModel some code that checks whether you have an Internet connection or not. Or in the method that makes the API call to get the data.

In the next lesson from that tutorial, "Behind the scenes", they talk about offline mode.

Comment: Yeah, so I saw and they don't have an offline mode but their app doesn't crash because of the older versions of the libraries they are using. After I updated the libraries in their project, even their app crashed when there was no internet.

The problem I have is that I can't access an application context within the ViewModel so how am i supposed to check for internet connectivity

Comment: There are two options here: 1. use AndroidViewModel that needs context being passed from the fragment when you create the viewModel and check for connectivity in the viewModel. 2. Stick to ViewModel, create a function in the fragment that checks for Internet connectivity and pass that value to a variable in the viewModel.